# Authentication with HTTP Account with XPiNC "Run saver-based XPages app directly on server"

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

I'm trying to make an Auto-Login with HTTP Accounts in XPiNC with the option "Run saver-based XPages app directly on server".

I found a ibm documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_forms_xpinconserver.html?lang=en) but it does not work for me.

I used exacly the same url in the http accound I would use in the browser, I also add in the "XPages Performance" setting an "Run the following XPages application directly on the server" option with the same host name I would use in the browser

Is there any setting I miss to tell the Client to use HTTP Accounts?

FYI: I'm using Notes and Domino Version 9.0.1FP2

[UPDATE]
My Problem is that the Auto-Login does not work, if i make a manuel login, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question what's not working, whether it's not loading the application in XPiNC or just not auto-logging on.

Have you enabled the setting on the database? The details in Mastering XPages Second Edition outlining the steps in order was very useful for me.

There's an admin checklist including running server-based apps on server in XPiNC in my Domino 9.0.1 whitepaper, "Maximising The Benefits of IBM Domino 9.0.1 With XPages", here http://www.intec.co.uk/quickstarts-training/

Comment: It's worth checking the account in your personal address book. The account server name needs to point to the actual NSF, not just the server. Once you manually log in, it should also have a login name and password set, I believe.

Comment: The URL points to the NSF including server and it have a login name and a password but it still does not work